# How to select a web element in R when CSS selector is not available?

Tags: css, r, web, download, web-scraping

I want in R to download the data I get from the following website by clicking the "Download" button on the right.

http://www.comstage.de/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?p=146223984

I wanted to do it with RSelenium and use SelectorGadget to find the CSS of the button. However, the button has no CSS. Are there ways to do what I want in R?

Usually I would do it like in the code below but this needs a CSS.

```
library("RSelenium")

startServer()
#checkForServer()

mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()

mybrowser$navigate("http://www.comstage.de/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?p=146223984")

button1 <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#ctl00_content_disclaimerControl_disclaimerConfirmControl_btnIndividual")
button1$clickElement()

downloadbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "????????")
downloadbutton$clickElement()
```

Comment: You are confusing CSS with CSS selectors. You don't need an element's computed styles to select it using a selector.

Comment: But how can I figure out how to find an selector for the button?

Comment: You can use "inspect the webpage" with google chrome. I am not able to load the page http://www.comstage.de/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?p=146223984